# ADODB Stream convert binary to string

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I'm facing a problem when trying to open a file from a URL using ADODB, and then using that as a string stream. Basically, the issue I'm facing is *almost* a duplicate of this question here:

[convert ADODB binary stream to string vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33860833/convert-adodb-binary-stream-to-string-vba)

Except that I have to use an ADODB Stream to work with the content later on. Therefore, skipping ADODB completely is not an option, like in the answer in the other topic.
Right now, what I'm doing is making a HTTP GET Request, using a **binary** stream to save it as a file, then loading that very same file using a **text** stream. This works just fine, but there has to be a way to skip the saving-loading part and make it work directly.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Dim myURL As String
myURL = "https://xyz.xyz/xyz.csv"
Dim WinHttpReq As Object
Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
WinHttpReq.Open "GET", myURL, False
WinHttpReq.Send

Dim objStream, strData
Dim leftcellstarttemp As Variant, rightcellstarttemp As Variant, leftcellendtemp As Variant, rightcellendtemp As Variant, r As Long, line As String, dtStr As String, mlValue As String, dtArr() As String

myURL = WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WinHttpReq.ResponseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile "C:\Temp\file1.csv", 2
    oStream.Close

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Charset = "utf-8"
    objStream.Type = 2
    objStream.Open
    objStream.LoadFromFile "C:\Temp\file1.csv"
    line = objStream.ReadText(-2)
End If

Do Until objStream.EOS
(and so on, and so forth...)
```

Can you help me on how I can get past this needless file saving-loading process?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a text stream for the first part (since the response is plain text) ?

Comment: I did try that before, but unfortunately the response is not written into the stream. For some reason, it has to be binary to accept the input.